# Replace an sqlite database from another C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

In my project I have one SqlCypher Database say A.db and which is used by the app.

At some point I will get latest data which I have in another SqlCypher db, say B.db.

Both databases has identical structure (tables).

Now how can I replace the entire data of Database A from Database B. All the table name and structure are same.

How can I achieve this using any Query?, or Should I go for a StreamReader..

It is a Xamarin Project which uses ORMLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing what benefit it brings to the project and how it impacts the effort. It was always better for using a locking mechanism rather than a two Db approach.